# problems with \o after redefining \O

Tags: math-mode, macros, accents

I redefined the `\O` command for math purposes but now it seems to conflict with the `\o` command, which I need for people's names. So far, the problem seems to occur only in the author entry. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter\let\OO\O\let\O\@undefined\makeatother
\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal O}
\begin{document}
\author{R{\o}n}
\title{Hi}
\maketitle
Hi R{\o}n, I like $\O_X$.
\end{document}
```

If you remove the `{\o}` from the author entry, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Isn't it better to *not* redefine `\O`, and instead do e.g. `\newcommand{\OO}{\mathcal{O}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `amsart` class applies `\MakeUppercase` to the author name when doing `\maketitle`. Since the `\MakeUppercase` macro changes `\o` into `\O`, you get an error.

You *could* do

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\let\latexO\O
\let\O\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\O}{\ifmmode\mathcal{O}\else\latexO\fi}

\begin{document}

\author{R{\o}n}
\title{Hi}
\maketitle

Hi R{\o}n, I like $\O_X$.

\end{document}
```

but the risk of shooting yourself in the foot is not really avoided: under some circumstances the wrong meaning for `\O` could still be picked up.

***Don't*** do it; use a meaningful name for `\mathcal{O}` instead.

Comment: a-ha! So that's the culprit. Thanks!